# Unity VR - Teleportation script doesn't precisely teleport to where I'm pointing to

Tags: unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

I'm pretty new when it comes to Unity and VR. I have to implement a teleport script and pretty much the only thing I know is that I can't move the camera itself because any changes to that are overwritten instantly. Instead, I use the XR Origin object as a locomotion platform and move that. The script is added as a component to the right hand and essentially just takes the XR Origin object and an XR Ray Interactor component from the hand and when I press the trigger it moves the XR Origin position to the position where the ray hits a teleportation area.

```
var hit = rayInteractor.TryGetHitInfo(out Vector3 position, out _, out _, out _);
if (hit && triggerPress.action.ReadValue<float>() == 1f)
    {
        player.transform.position = position;
    }
```

However, the actual camera does not end up in the correct position as can be seen by debug output:

> Camera: (0.84, 0.92, -0.94), XROrigin: (1.74, 0.00, -2.55), ray hit position: (1.74, 0.00, -2.55)

I do understand why that happens. The XR Origin object is a 1m² area and the camera can be at any point within that area so when I change the position of the XR Origin object the camera might simply not be in the middle of the object. I can fix that by setting the XR Origin scale to 0.1 for X and Z and that does result in pretty much perfect precision:

> Camera: (4.02, 0.97, 0.14), XROrigin: (4.09, 0.00, 0.00), ray hit position: (4.09, 0.00, 0.00)

However, that also breaks the visuals. The hand is way too small and super far away from the camera:

[in both screenshots the headset is at head height and the controller is lying on a table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PQrAY.jpg)

How would I go about writing a teleport script that manages to teleport me to the exact location without breaking any visuals? Is there some trick I don't know about? Most tutorials are completely useless to me cause I need the teleportation to happen in VS and not just in Unity itself

Edit: here's a screenshot showing how extreme the differences are at times
[red circle marks where I actually ended up at](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TfLVh.png)

Edit 2: So two ideas how to fix it: 1) maybe the camera is set to a fixed position within the XR Origin object and I just need to adjust the starting positin of the camera and 2) I could just calculate the difference between camera and destination and add that to the XR Origin position. I can't test either until next week, though

Answer (score 0):

I think if you only move the `XROrigin` your camera still maintains the same offset relative to it as before.

What I mean by that is

- Let's assume you start at `XROrigin (0,0,0)` and `Camera (1, 0, 0)` (because you already walked to the right)
- Now you run your script and move `XROrigin (0, 0, 1)`

I would expect your camera to actually end up at `(1, 0, 1)` maintaining the offset.

I think what you should use instead is [`XROrigin.MoveCameraToWorldLocation(Vector3)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.core-utils@2.4/api/Unity.XR.CoreUtils.XROrigin.html#Unity_XR_CoreUtils_XROrigin_MoveCameraToWorldLocation_UnityEngine_Vector3_)

> This function moves the camera to the world location provided by `desiredWorldLocation`. It does this by moving the `XR Origin` object so that the camera's world location matches the `desiredWorldLocation`

```
var hit = rayInteractor.TryGetHitInfo(out Vector3 position, out _, out _, out _);
if (hit && triggerPress.action.ReadValue<float>() == 1f)
{
    player.GetComponent<XROrigin>().MoveCameraToWorldLocation(position);
}
```

might want to maintain current camera height though

```
var hit = rayInteractor.TryGetHitInfo(out Vector3 position, out _, out _, out _);
if (hit && triggerPress.action.ReadValue<float>() == 1f)
{
    var xrOrigin = player.GetComponent<XROrigin>();
    position.y = xrOrigin.Camera.transform.position.y;
    xrOrigin.MoveCameraToWorldLocation(position);
}
```

---

**NOTE**: Regarding `triggerPress.action.ReadValue<float>() == 1f` this might fail due to floating point precision. You should rather configure your action accordingly to only be triggered at a certain threshold in the first place and then rather use [`triggerPress.action.trigerred`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.inputsystem@1.8/api/UnityEngine.InputSystem.InputAction.html#UnityEngine_InputSystem_InputAction_triggered)

Comment: That's what I would've tried by hand but the method is exactly what I was looking for. I can't upvote your comment or mark it as the answer so thanks for that and for the trigger hint. I tried a different way before which didn't work but action.triggered worked as expected